# How do I create a factory for models that have a has_one/belongs_to relationship with validations that are usually overcome by nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, factory-bot

I have an Account model that has_one User model, and a User model that belongs_to Account model. I think that the basic code required for demonstration is:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
  validates_presence_of :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  # validates_presence_of :account # this is not actually present,
                                   # but is implied by a not null requirement
                                   # in the database, so it only takes effect on
                                   # save or update, instead of on #valid?
end
```

When I define associations in each factory:

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.association :account
end

Factory.define :account do |f|
  f.association :user
end
```

I get a stack overflow, as each is creating an account/user recursively.

The way I've been able to solve this is to emulate nested attribute forms in my tests:

```
before :each do
  account_attributes = Factory.attributes_for :account
  account_attributes[:user_attributes] = Factory.attributes_for :user
  @account = Account.new(account_attributes)
end
```

However, I'd like to keep this logic in the factory, as it can get out of hand once I start adding other modules:

```
before :each do
  account_attributes = Factory.attributes_for :account
  account_attributes[:user_attributes] = Factory.attributes_for :user
  account_attributes[:user_attributes][:profile_attributes] = Factory.attributes_for :profile
  account_attributes[:payment_profile_attributes] = Factory.attributes_for :payment_profile
  account_attributes[:subscription_attributes] = Factory.attributes_for :subscription
  @account = Account.new(account_attributes)
end
```

Please help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using factory_girl's after_build callback.

```
Factory.define :account do |f|
  f.after_build do |account|
    account.user ||= Factory.build(:user, :account => account)
    account.payment_profile ||= Factory.build(:payment_profile, :account => account)
    account.subscription ||= Factory.build(:subscription, :account => account)
  end
end

Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.after_build do |user|
    user.account ||= Factory.build(:account, :user => user)
    user.profile ||= Factory.build(:profile, :user => user)
  end
end
```

This will create the associated classes before the owning class is saved, so validations pass.

Comment: where did `user.profile` come from? Is this meant to be `user.account`?

Comment: user.profile is a model that stores information about the user associated with the account. So, the structure is Account > User > Profile. I added user.account, though, as I think that is necessary if creating a user directly.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [factory_girl documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/1.3.3/frames). The way you're building those accounts seems like you're not really taking advantage of factory_girl.

I've always taken care of associations by creating the objects that I need before testing. I'm going to take a stab at this based on the models you're referencing above:

```
before :each do
  @account = Factory(:account, :user_id => Factory(:user).id, :profile_id => Factory(:profile).id)
end
```

Now `@account` will have `@account.user` and `@account.profile` available. If you need to define those, `@profile = @account.profile` works just great.

Comment: The issue I'm having is that user belongs_to account instead of the reverse, so Account#user_id doesn't exists, and User#account_id is the attribute that needs to get set. However, I can't save an account to get the id without an account having an associated user attached.